# Planetary.js Texts on markers

Tags: javascript

I´m using [planetaryjs](http://planetaryjs.com/) to make a 3d globe that drops some location pins.
Here´s a useful example: https://codepen.io/perskes/pen/mxyPWM using the function

```
planet.plugins.pings.add
```

However I can´t find a way to draw some text along with the markers . 
There are some examples to draw shapes on the documentation but I don't find it very clear.
http://planetaryjs.com/documentation/plugins.html

Has anyone tried to do this or knows any alternative to get similar results?

Comment: I also need this @onironauta, inform me when you get this